# What is the fastest way to draw X amount of circles in HTML5 canvas?

Tags: html, performance, canvas, html5-canvas

Simple question regarding the speed of canvas drawing.

Would it be quicker to draw 100 circles in 1 canvas, or 1 circle in 100 canvases?

Comment: I haven't yet done a performance test, I thought I'd query it on here first. It is using path methods yes. What do you mean by drawing to an off screen canvas? does this assume every circle will be identical?

Comment: prepare buffers in multiple workers, arrange them together and put into canvas. but this must be harder than using direct drawing commands

Comment: This is a per case problem and all comes down to "make test perfs" with your requirements. For a single size of circles with a single color putImageData is the fastest with high numbers of entities (>5000). Below, drawImage(offscreenCanvas) is just as fast as needed. For constantly changing sizes circles with the same color, a single path made up of all your circles can be faster up to 20000 entities. So myself, for constantly changing sizes circles in <20 groups of colors with > 15000 circles, (yeah plots...) I do sort my circles by color and draw them with the single path option.

Answer (score -1):

It is a lot easier to draw 100 circles in one canvas:

When you have the same actions called, whether it is 1 canvas * 100 circles, or 100 canvases * 1 circle, **you are still telling the program to draw the exact same amount of times**.

So what's the difference?

When you introduce 100 canvases to the program, the program will run much slower because it needs to store these in the background. Although the speed won't decrease too much, it will still decrease.

Another benefit for 1 canvas is that it is a lot easier to control one canvas with everything on it, rather than 100 canvases.

Edit: On one canvas, you can also have the circles overlap (if you want), but if you have 100 canvases, the circles can not overlap.

I hope this helped you :)